# How to use SQLite3 library in MSVC project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, sqlite, dll

I want to build a native C++ application using sqlite3.dll. I tried to build it from SQLite amalgamation source. It creates the dll and the lib file (is the lib the dll's import library?) but when I use it in my project, I get errors like

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _sqlite3_open referenced in function...
```

I tried to prefix underscore in the def file (I set the Module Definition File in the Linker Input options), but tough luck.

What am I doing wrong? It looks like the reference is missing: I added SQLite.lib (the lib file I created) in the Additional Dependencies in the Project where I want to use it. I added its directory to Library Directories.

I use MSVC 2010 Express and I am just about to curse it.

Comment: These are exacly the errors I get when I forget to add the right sqlite3.lib into  the additional dependencies of the linker.

Comment: @Christophe I do not specify the path in the Additional dependencies, just the lib names - and the path to them is in Library directories - is this right?

Comment: Should work. The dll was build with right options (ie 32 or 64 bits)  ?  And the file  is .cpp and not .c ?

Comment: @Christophe yes, of course.

Comment: Try to put the fill pathname of the .lib in the additional linker dependencies (next to kernel.lib, etc...).  Just to be sure.  THen inspect your .lib file using `dumpbin /exports sqlite3.lib` to verify the expected symbols are exported with the correct naming convention (i.e. as displayed in your error message).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error when trying to compile using sqlite3\_open in Visual Studio 2013](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28776898/error-when-trying-to-compile-using-sqlite3-open-in-visual-studio-2013)