# Error when trying to compile using sqlite3_open in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sqlite, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I'm working in a Cocos2dx (c++) win 32 project and trying to use sqlite to save the game data. My knowledge of c++ / Visual Studio is very limited right now.

This is part of the code that I'm trying to compile.

```
#include <sqlite3\include\sqlite3.h>
...
void HelloWorld::SaveAndLoadTest()
{
 sqlite3 *pdb = NULL;    
 sqlite3_open("writablePath", &pdb);
 ...
}
```

But when I try to compile the line with the sqlite3_open command I get the following error:

***Error    7   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _sqlite3_open referenced in function...***

I've been trying to find an answer for this many hours. The most similar question I found was this one but I don't understand the answer.
[Error: undefined reference to `sqlite3_open'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9389344/error-undefined-reference-to-sqlite3-open)

> *You need to link the sqlite3 library along with your program:*
>
> ```
> g++ main.cpp -lsqlite3
> ```

I'm new to Visual Studio and I don't understand how to solve this, anyone?

Comment: Have you added sqlite3.lib to your additional dependencies in your VS project (linker options of the project) ?

Comment: Hi, no probably not. Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies. Is this the place to do it?

Comment: do you know how to "link" a library into your project? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba1z7822.aspx

Comment: Wow, that was TOO easy! Thank you both for holding my hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error LNK2019 means that references are missing probably because a library is mising.

To add sqlite to a MSVC project, you have to make sure that:

- the header is included in your source files
- `sqlite3.dll` is in the path or in the directory of the executable
- AND that `sqlite3.lib` is added to the additional dependencies in the VS project (options of the project > Linker > Input > Additional dependencies)

This last point is mandatory, because the lib tells the linker which functions are stored in the dll.

Comment: Be sure you add sqlite3.lib to your Additional Dependencies for both Debug and Release modes.

Answer (score 1):

The solution, quite simply, is to link `sqlite3` to your project. Libraries need to be linked (via the linker) for you to be able to use them. Head over [here](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html) and download the pre-compiled binaries for your platform of choice (in this case, Win32). You may also choose to compile `sqlite3` from source. You should end up with a `.lib` file. Go to `Project -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> General -> Additional Include Directories` and add the path to your library file to it. Then go to `Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies` and put in `sqlite3.lib`.

Answer (score 1):

And remember that you must build sqlite3.lib from file SQLite3.def:

1. Download source from source (https://www.sqlite.org/download.html)

For example: source https://www.sqlite.org/2022/sqlite-amalgamation-3390300.zip

Or download binary from binary

For example: binary https://www.sqlite.org/2022/sqlite-dll-win64-x64-3390300.zip

2. Extract both archives to the same directory

Open Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017 by typing Developer Command in Windows Search

Go to directory where you've extracted source code and binary files (via opened cmd)

3. Run lib /DEF:sqlite3.def /OUT:sqlite3.lib /MACHINE:x64
   (Remember if win32, replace "MACHINE:x64" by MACHINE:x86)